# Hi, I like to review stuff. Is that ok?

Tags: discussion, reviewing-behavior

A while ago, I used to post a hundreds of questions and answers on the SE network. These days, I do not have the time for that, a post or two per month at most.

The thing is though: I never closed the tab.

Instead of posting I have watched the review queues, usually checking them 2-3 times a day. Over time, that adds up to quiet a few reviews. This has become a part of my daily routine, and reading a couple of posts and dropping a comment does not take a lot more time than making a cup of tea with milk.

Well, that is about it, I just have a question:

**Can I just continue to do that?**

I am reading posts and sometimes lurk in the chat to keep in touch with the community, but is reviewing without posting fundamentally a [bad-habit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-habit)?

Comment: I only read interesting questions, up voting them and post an answer if I have one.  To all the reviewers who corrected grammar, fixed formatting or suggested improvements THANK YOU. If everybody was like me this community would be a total mess.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

People participate in the site in different ways.  Some have lots of questions, some prefer to answer, some help out with "meta" stuff like keeping tagging sane, some guide new users, some review... If reviewing is what you want to focus on right now, that's fine.  So long as you're staying abreast of community norms -- for example, you have a good handle on scope when working in the Close and Reopen queues -- and you spend the time needed to evaluate each review item, you'll be helping the site.